# Delete Page vs Redirect to Home Page - Unwanted but 300 Organic Traffic Page

Tags: seo, google

I have a blog post with 300 organic traffic per months (It is about 0.5% traffic of all traffic)

This blog post isn't quality, but it is something like unethical type of post. It gives bad reputation for our blog.

So I wanted to remove it.

Should I delete it or redirect to Home page? What is the better for SEO? [There is no way to edit that article as ethcal article..]

Comment: I personally prefer using a custom 404 for stuff like this. I am not a fan of redirecting to a home page though there may be good reasons that another could cite. I would think about what is right for the user and retention. The home page could be good for retention depending on how well it was created. Tough call really. Cheers!!